USA Horror\Slasher from late 70s\early 80s with a crazy old woman
A "classic" plot where a bunch of youth come to a house. One after another is slayed with a kind of hatchet or a cane, I don't remember. In large parts of the movie we only see the back or the hands from the crazy killer. It ends when this old, grumpy witchlike woman suddenly appears. I think she appears in the living room in the last ten, fifteen minutes and goes crazy on the last of the survivors. I can vaguely remember that the witch ends up drowned in the outdoor pool. 
I think the name of the movie was something like "The House of Fear"(translated from Norwegian), but I cannot find any match for this title

Corrected 'hatch' to 'hatchet' but only because I think in retrospect it's what you meant. ;)

This sounds a bit like The House on Sorority Row from 1983, but the ending is different. Maybe you just remembered it wrong, because this movie:

Has an old, cranky woman dying in a pool (and her body is dumped in it)
Has someone that we keep seeing from behind and who might be that old woman killing the girls in the house (who are responsible for her death) with her sharp falcon-headed cane (here's a picture of a similar cane from the 2009 remake)
Is called House of Evil in some countries.

The final girl was played by Kate McNeil. Here's the trailer:




I think you are right, Walt, once again! Looks very similar. Thank you!
